# Perl or Python Arbitrary Regex Replacement with Capture

Tags: regex, perl

I have scripts that will take a dictionary file as an input (hash/dict) and search files and do replaces. This is trivial in either Perl or Python. I also have a script in Python that will take regex from a config file and use it to do things. What I can't figure out, is how to take a regex dictionary, essentially, from a file, and use it to do replacements if I have group references in the replacement.

Simple example code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @input_file = ("XYABCD134"
                 ,"DFE*(&FDS"
                 ,"YDSF%@%d325"
                 ,"ABCD134DS");

my %dict = ('(\w+)BCD(\w+)', '$1EFG$2');

my $done = 0;

foreach my $line (@input_file) {
  foreach my $re (keys %dict){
    $done = 0;
    if ($line =~ /$re/) {
      $line =~ s/$re/$dict{$re}/g;
      print  "$line\n";
      $done = 1;
      last;
    }
  }
  print  "$line\n" unless $done;
}
```

Desired output in this case should be
XYAEFG134 for the first line, but I get $1EFG$2.

I can't get the numbered groups to work properly, either hardcoded into the dictionary in the script, or coming from my external config file. In Python I'm even less sure of how to get match.group(1) or whatever to work coming from text like this. The only way I know to make this work is to hardcode the entire regex into its own block, and I'd rather just give this to folks who don't necessarily know perl or Python and have them be able to write their own regex without modifying the code. I know there's programs people have written that can do this, but I'm limited in what I can use and provide to others in my environment.

Comment: Tip: `if ($line =~ /$re/) { $line =~ s/$re/$dict{$re}/g; ... }` is a poor way or writing `if ($line =~ s/$re/$dict{$re}/g) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami Good call. I think I was a bit in python mode and a bit in just getting it to work (after the first time I accidentally wrote every line multiple times because I had multiple dict entries).

Comment: You also compile each pattern for each line which is super wasteful. Use qr// to compiled them before the loop.

Comment: Finally, you also have a the problem that if you have rules A -> B and B -> C, you could end up with B or C if you start with A.

Comment: @ikegami you mean because hashes in perl aren't ordered if I have a line that matches more than one of my rules, it'll change which gets executed randomly on multiple executions? I suppose that isn't great, but this is also quick and dirty, so I'm not sure I'm concerned.

Comment: The ambiguity is because hash are unordered. But even if they weren't, you could still have a problem. Imagine if you want to swap two words. You'd end with with `s/true/false/g; s/false/true/g;` or `s/true/false/g; s/false/true/g;`. It doesn't matter if you don't know which one you'll get because neither works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You want [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution)'s `gsub_modify`.

---

Would you expect the following to print `123`?

```perl
my $x = 123;
my $y = '$x';
say $y;
```

No, so why would you expect any different in your snippet?

```perl
s{...}{...}
```

is a shorthand for

```perl
s{...}{ qq{...} }e
```

so

```perl
s/$re/$dict{$re}/g
```

is equivalent to

```perl
s/$re/ "$dict{$re}" /eg
```

Whichever way you look at it, there's no `$1` in the code. The string literal only contain `$dict{$re}`, so only `$dict{$re}` gets interpolated.

Comment: If I didn't want to use a CPAN module (or couldn't, more likely) is there a way to essentially "unquote" my string and turn it into literals? Obviously the module accomplishes it, so it's possible I guess.

Comment: Anyone can. If they can install a script, they can install a module. If you choose not too, well that's on you. I'm not going to reimplement the module for you. Why would you want someone's untested or barely tested SO code over someone's well tested CPAN code anway?